# Issue with object persistence in database ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I'm trying to implement a registration system in an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application. Once an event has occurred, the administrator should be able to click on a button to mark a user as having attended the event. This currently works for one time events, but for reccurring events I'm having some trouble getting the information to persist in the database.

At the moment this is what my registration model looks like:

```
public class Registration
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public int EventId { get; set; }

        public bool Attended { get; set; }

        public IDictionary<string, bool> AttendedRecurring { get; set; }
    }
```

The idea is, if the event is recurring, the dates that the user does attend the event are stored in the AttendedRecurring dictionary where the date they attend is a string, and the bool indicates whether the user attended or not. I've tried implementing this as an ICollection as well (just keep a list of dates of when the user attends) and I have the same issue.

The issue comes in when I try to add things to the dictionary or view what's in the dictionary.

I have some code in one of my views that adds a date to the dictionary whenever a button is pressed. Here it is:

```
var registrationToMark = db.Registrations.Find(registrationId);

if (registrationToMark.AttendedRecurring == null)
{
     registrationToMark.AttendedRecurring = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
}

registrationToMark.AttendedRecurring.Add(occurrenceDate, true);

db.Entry(registrationToMark).State = EntityState.Modified;

db.SaveChanges();

Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

I've set breakpoints in this and whenever I do, registrationToMark looks exactly the way it should before it's saved to the database. However, when the page reloads, AttendedRecurring is null again and it seems as though nothing has been saved.

I've had similar issues trying to save other kinds of objects in a database when they're not stored in another table (structs, lists, etc) so I'm guessing I'm not understanding something about object persistence. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I don't think EF can handle `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` out of the box.  It only understands basic keyless collection types, like `List<T>`, arrays.

Comment: If you only need to know which events they attended then change it to `IList<DateTime>` and just save that.  From your description it sounds like it would end up being a list of dates in string format (ugh) with a bool value set to true.  Do you really need the bool?

Comment: I don't but I'm pretty sure I tried using IList as well as ICollection and it didn't work which is why I tried dictionaries. But I'll take another look - thank you!